# Pyspark cannot find table when reading Postgresql

Tags: python, postgresql, apache-spark, pyspark

Run my pyspark script:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

# Spark session & context
spark = (SparkSession
         .builder
         .master("spark://spark-master:7077")
         .appName("read-postgres-jdbc")
         # Add postgres jar
         .config("spark.driver.extraClassPath", "/opt/workspace/postgresql-9.4.1207.jar")
         .getOrCreate())
sc = spark.sparkContext

df = (
    spark.read
    .format("jdbc")
    .option("driver", "org.postgresql.Driver")
    .option("url", "jdbc:postgresql://postgres/postgres")
    .option("dbtable", "public.""ASSET_DATA""")
    .option("user", "airflow")
    .option("password", "airflow")
    .load()
)
```

and it yields the following error message saying "public.asset_data" doesn't exist. However, I can select it in pgAdmin.

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o69.load.
: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "public.asset_data" does not exist
  Position: 15
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2182)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1911)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:173)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:622)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:472)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeQuery(PgStatement.java:386)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRDD$.resolveTable(JDBCRDD.scala:61)
```

Comment: What is the name of the table in the database? If this, `"public.""ASSET_DATA"""` is supposed to yield `public.ASSET_DATA` it is getting to the database as `public.asset_data`. So either your quoting is not correct or the error is coming from somewhere else.

Comment: ASSET_DATA is the table name and public is the DB schema. I am not familiar with postgresql and it seems I need use double quotes for the table name in order to have postgresql to recognize it as a table in pgadmin. ```SELECT * FROM public."ASSET_DATA";```. Just tried removing the double quotes would yield the same error message.

Comment: @ilovejames Was my answer helpful if yes please accept and upvote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the `quotes` using `backslash`. Try like below

```
df = (
    spark.read
    .format("jdbc")
    .option("driver", "org.postgresql.Driver")
    .option("url", "jdbc:postgresql://postgres/postgres")
    .option("dbtable", "public.\"ASSET_DATA\"")
    .option("user", "airflow")
    .option("password", "airflow")
    .load()
)
```

Comment: After updating the way to call the DB table like you described, it worked! Thanks.